# put a name value inside the div id

Tags: javascript, php, html, echo

here is the BUTTON from the index.php to open the Modal form;

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" value="#01" name="btn" class="button2 btn btn-success model_open" data-btnval = "#01" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" >form</a>
```

this is the script to get the value of the current button;

```
$(document).on("click", ".model_open", function () {
var btnval = $(this).data('btnval'); 

   $(".modal-body #btnval").text( btnval );
$('#hiddenid').val(btnval );
});
```

and this is the Modal Form echoing the button value "#01"

```
<!-- Modal header starts -->                                                
                    <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                          <div class="modal-dialog">
                              <div class="modal-content">
                                  <div class="modal-header1" style="padding:10px 15px;">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >&times;</button>
                                    <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>MODAL FORM</h4>
                            </div>
                                <div class="modal-body" style="padding:10px 10px;">
<!-- Modal header ends -->

            <div id="btnval"></div> <!-- Echo the button value "#01" -->

<!-- Modal Application form starts -->  
                 <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="confirmation.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <!-- First Name Filed Starts -->
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">NAME</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="NEXT">
```

when click NEXT button in the Modal Form, it will proceed to the 2nd page to dsiplay all of the information from Modal form together with the button value "#01";

```
<form id="main-contact-form1"  style="background-color: #f0f8ff; padding: 20px;" class="contact-form1" name="contact-form1" method="post" action="sendappli.php" role="form">   


                      <div class="label-field-pair">
                        <label>ID</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id='id' name='id' value='<?php echo $_GET["btnval"]; ?>'  />
                      </div>

          <div class="label-field-pair">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id='name' name='name' value='<?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?>'  />
                      </div>
```

checking the provided information before it will send to my email address.

problem: I can't get the value of "btnval" from `<div id="btnval">` that need to have a NAME to get its value and echoing it to `<?php echo $GET[posible name of btnval];?/>` at the 2nd page????

[image]

Comment: what you are trying to achieve? what's the purpose of `<?php echo $_GET["sample"]; ?>`on second page?

Comment: I have set of form on my modal which has I echoed the button value from the first page. inside the modal form, there is a "NEXT" button to proceed to the 2nd page, on the second page there has a form which is to display or echo the information from the modal form, and I like to echo the button value also.

Comment: please see updated post. ^^ thank you

Comment: bro you change you change your question why ...?

Comment: hello there, now is more specific. but the question is the same. "How could I insert a NAME inside the <div id="btnval"> to get of its value and echoing it to second page by using this code <?php echo $GET[posible name of btnval];?/>

Comment: If i am not wrong in last form text field of ID you want to set div content of id `btnval` and currently getting underfined index error, so i would suggest to putt Next button click function `$('#id').val($("#btnval").text())`

Comment: hello @Vipul thank you for the code. can you show me the set of your function code to run?

Comment: @MarvinAcosta can you check this : http://jsfiddle.net/0avjev7g/

Comment: hello @vipul sorry for late response. I tried your code and it didn't work also :( any another idea?

Comment: @awl19 please have time to see my post. thank you

Answer (score 2):

see the below code

```
var div= document.getElementById('btnval');
div.setAttribute('name', 'sample');
```

or:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0].setAttribute("name", "sample");
```

Comment: hello @sumit thank you for the idea. please see updated post. ^^ thank you

Answer (score 0):

use `load` method to get div from `first page` to `second page`

```
$("#div").load("/firstpage.html #btnval");
```

load `div` using its `id` on second page

Comment: hello @Bhargav thank you for your time, I tied your code but I got an error --> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attributes instead.

```
<div id="btnval" data-name="sample">
```

Then you can pass it to another page as a url parameter using jquery and then get it using,

```
<?php echo $_GET["sample"]; ?>
```

Comment: Hi @Chandimal thank you for the idea, I tried your code but I got an error -->  Undefined index: sample

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

1) index.php

```
<div id="btnval">Hello This My Div</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var div = document.getElementById('btnval');
    div.setAttribute('name', 'sample');
</script>
```

2) demo.php

```
<?php
include 'index.php'; // include your other files
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(document.getElementById('btnval').innerHTML);
    var div = document.getElementById('btnval');
    console.log(div.getAttribute('name'));
</script>
```

Comment: hello, @Krupal thank you for the code, but my <div id="btnval"> is the ECHO value button from the index.php which I echoed on the Modal Form using javascript. all code is perfectly well processed. I just like to put a name inside the <div id="btnval"> to get the value of this id "btnval" and echoing it to the 2nd page.